# Can I find all (checked) exceptions which may be thrown in a block of Groovy code?

Tags: java, exception, groovy

I'm doing maintenance on a Groovy application which has decidedly substandard error handling- countless instances of `catch (Exception e) {}` all over the place. I want to implement far more fine-grained exception handling, but in order to do this I need to know which exceptions a given handler block can expect to catch- and since Groovy does not follow Java's checked exception rules, this is non-trivial.

If I had a robust testing platform for this app I would simply remove all the handlers and then test it until I had a comprehensive list of ways it can fall over- but unfortunately this code is part of a rather messy distributed application which exists largely in production, and depends on custom hardware, so creating a testbed for it is a much bigger task than I currently have the resources for.

So, I'm wondering if there is any shortcut (a particular IDE with the right magic, even) by which I can analyse the code and get a list of all possible exceptions a given statement might throw?

Comment: Even if it were written in Java source, what's to say that the application doesn't throw unchecked exceptions?

Comment: See the question title- I am primarily interested in checked exceptions. Unchecked ones are, as you say, a constant.

Comment: I guess my point is, if that code base primarily uses unchecked exceptions to get around (say it uses Spring and Hibernate, for instance), what's the point of even doing the exercise?

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that all instances of `catch (Exception ex) {}` were put there because they were ported from Java code (when the programmer was too lazy to handle them) *and* the programmer never meant for the flow to continue, you should just be able to replace all instances of that code with:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

Short of doing that, I don't see how you're going to effectively change a code base without knowing how it's supposed to work (or having tests that know how it's supposed to work). Even if there were a tool to enumerate all of the possible checked exceptions, how would you know which ones to handle and which ones to re-throw without knowing the ways in which the app was meant to fall over?

Comment: This is not a case of ported Java code- this is a case of the original programmer writing in Groovy, and wanting flow to continue in spite of any exceptions that might arise. This is generally speaking still what we want to happen, at least in most cases. But in some cases there may be multiple exceptions arising, some we ignore, some we simply log, and others which may prove to be fatal.

Comment: My reason for asking is that if I can see a breakdown of which exceptions can happen at a certain point- and where they come from further down the stack- I can hopefully differentiate between stuff to be ignored and stuff to be handled. With the current approach of catch-all-and-ignore everywhere, it's impossible.

Comment: (also, you're right that what I'm trying to do here is pretty futile- I know that already. But in the absence of proper resources and environment, I must simply do what I can with what I have)